# How long does VSTS keep a branch once it is deleted?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

There is an option to delete the branch and once it is deleted, we can recover it using the search using the exact match.

How long does the branch remain and can be recovered once it is deleted?

Comment: TFVC or Git? Please add the appropriate tag....

Comment: @jessehouwing sorry added git

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Git the branch tag is deleted, but the commits will remain. VSTS doesn't perform server side garbage collection and the commits will stay there and will be recoverable. The only way to really destroy a branch is to create a local clone, deleting the repository on VSTS, creating a new bare repository on VSTS (can use the same name) and push the content back in.

In TFVC a branch is only soft-deleted on a delete, you'll need to perform a destroy action from the commandline (`tf destroy $/Project/Branch/To/Destroy`) for the branch to be really gone. Though, even after destroying it takes a little more time before the cleanup processes will expunge the data in the database.